# Why does Gmail search sometimes misorder the dates?

Tags: gmail

Example: a search returning these three matches shows them (Conversation view disabled) out of time-date order:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

(I've verified those dates are as per the Date: header field of each message.)

Perhaps this is connected with the left arrow (which has no tooltip to tell me what it means) on lines #2 and #3.

For what it is worth, with Conversation view enabled, the result is:

[image]

PS Here's a further example, Conversation view disabled:
[image]

and enabled:
[image]

so the cause would not seem to be sub-conversations.